# How to log server IP in exim main log

Tags: linux, exim

I'm sending mails using IP rotation in exim, I tried to log the server IP in exim log, using

```
log_selector = +all
```

in exim conf, but it's not logging the server IP in exim main log

Is it possible to log server IP in exim log,

I'm trying to get the number of emails sent from a particular IP?.

Comment: Are you trying to log incoming our outgoing requests? How does this IP rotation work? Does the server itself do that? A Router?

Comment: I'm trying to log the outgoing request, In my current setup, the first mails send from first IP, second mail from second IP and so on, So I would like to know, how many mails are send from a particular IP.

Comment: And how do you make sure e-mails are sent out using those IPs? Can you edit your question to reflect that setup?

Answer (score 0):

That capability is not in exim currently in a logging format.  There is an open feature request in the Exim bug tracker to provide just that.  I do not know of any expected timeline for development.